# How far can a sukkah's walls be from schach?

Tags: halacha, sukkah

How far can a sukkah's walls be from the schach?

I build a sukkah in the corner of a courtyard next to my house, which has a verandah running along side it. Potentially two walls of the sukkah could be formed by the two walls of my house but the verandah means that there is a distance between the walls and the schach.

In the past I've constructed two walls underneath the edge of the veranda but wonder if this is unnecessary if the house walls are close enough that they will count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this extract from Mishna 1, 10 in Succa with the Bartenura and Yiqar Tosfot Yom Tov.:

> פרק א - משנה י
>
> סֻכָּה גְדוֹלָה, שֶׁהִקִּיפוּהָ בְדָבָר שֶׁאֵין מְסַכְּכִים בּוֹ, אִם יֵשׁ תַּחְתָּיו אַרְבַּע אַמּוֹת, פְּסוּלָה: ‏

ר"ע מברטנורה  סֻכָּה גְדוֹלָה. כָּל שֶׁאִלּוּ יִנָּטֵל הַסְּכָךְ פָּסוּל, יִשָּׁאֵר בָּהּ שִׁבְעָה טְפָחִים עַל שִׁבְעָה טְפָחִים סְכָךְ כָּשֵׁר, זוֹ הִיא סֻכָּה גְּדוֹלָה: שֶׁהִקִּיפוּהָ בְדָבָר שֶׁאֵין מְסַכְּכִין בּוֹ. דַּוְקָא מִן הַצַּד אָמְרִינַן שֶׁאֵין סְכָךְ פָּסוּל פּוֹסֵל אֶלָּא בְּאַרְבַּע אַמּוֹת, מִשּׁוּם טַעֲמָא דְּדֹפֶן עֲקֻמָּה. אֲבָל בְּאֶמְצַע הַסֻּכָּה פּוֹסֵל בְּאַרְבָּעָה טְפָחִים. **וַאֲוִיר שֶׁאֵין שָׁם סְכָךְ כְּלָל {מב} בֵּין בָּאֶמְצַע בֵּין מִן הַצַּד, פּוֹסֵל בִּשְׁלֹשָׁה טְפָחִים**: (ר"ע מברטנורה).  ‏

Free space between the wall an the Succa, i.e. the horizontal component of the distance must be small than 3 tefachim, tefach is aproximatively 9 cm.

If this space is not empty but there is a non regular skhach, as matallic piece, the distance at the edge may reach 4 amot, aproximatively 2.4 m, and in a inner part of the skhach 4 tefachim, aproximatively 36 cm.

Comment: Thanks! So given the space is covered by veranda the distance can be up to 2.4 m?

Comment: Yes @Jacub. The best for Succa is if a friend who knows halachot see it in vivo

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I'm planning on discussing with my Rabbi too.

Comment: @kouty Can you explain what you mean by "and in a inner part of the skhach 4 tefachim"?

Comment: ,@JoshGrinberg the middle